# Facebook on Android Emulator Crashing (NullPointer) when calling show on FbDialog

Tags: java, android, facebook, emulation

When trying to authenticate with facebook, my app crashes. It reaches the line

```
new FbDialog(context, url, listener).show();
```

Specifically in the show() (which I can't see sadly). It only happens when I run the application on an emulator (tried on version 2.2). It works fine on my actual phone (which admittedly is running 2.2.1 - is this likely to make a difference? I am struggling to download a later version at the moment but will keep trying if it is likely to be the cause)

Don't really know where to start with this so any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so dumb it is unreal - had commented out some code because it couldn't find the right Drawable in R. This code would only have been used if Facebook was not installed hence not happening on our phones.